# Alternative of TFS Label in Git Version Control

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Visual Studio Online. I have a solution which uses GIT version control system. Is there any labeling (we use Labels in TFS) support in GIT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for tags:

[Git - Tagging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging).

With tags you can name a changeset, which will be equivalent to TFS labels.

Note that tags in Git become a permanent part of your version history, if you need to move tags around, then you need to find a different tool for the job, like branches.

Comment: Only if you use an annotated tag.  Otherwise, lightweight tags are, well, just like branches.